# MsgPuck : How to compose an array of maps in msgpuck?

Tags: c, json, serialization, msgpack

I am trying to construct a [MsgPack](http://msgpack.org/index.html) object, using [MsgPuck library](http://rtsisyk.github.io/msgpuck/index.html) for the following JSON object:

```
{
    "Key_1": "val_1",
    "array_1": [ 
            {
                "key_3": "val_3",
                "key_4": "val_4"
            }
        ]
}
```

The following is my code:

```
{
    char buff[1024];
    char *ptr = buff;

    ptr = mp_encode_map(ptr, 2);
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "key_1", strlen("key_1"));
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "val_1", strlen("val_1"));
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "array_1", strlen("array_1"));
    ptr = mp_encode_array(ptr, 2);
    ptr = mp_encode_map(ptr, 2);
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "key_3", strlen("key_3"));
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "val_3", strlen("val_3"));
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "key_4", strlen("key_4"));
    ptr = mp_encode_str(ptr, "val_4", strlen("val_4"));

    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/test.mp","w");
    fwrite(buff, 1, ptr - buff, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

But the generated MsgPack data is as following:

```
$ xxd /tmp/test.mp
00000000: 82a5 6b65 795f 31a5 7661 6c5f 31a7 6172  ..key_1.val_1.ar
00000010: 7261 795f 3192 82a5 6b65 795f 33a5 7661  ray_1...key_3.va
// Expected val 91 -> ^^
00000020: 6c5f 33a5 6b65 795f 34a5 7661 6c5f 34    l_3.key_4.val_4
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

I found the problem in the code: I should use,

```
 ptr = mp_encode_array(ptr, 1);
```

instead of

```
 ptr = mp_encode_array(ptr, 2);
```

Comment: Why do you expect 91 there?

Comment: @ThomasJager, because that was the data I got when I encoded same data using another python library...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in the code: I should use,

```
 ptr = mp_encode_array(ptr, 1);
```

instead of

```
 ptr = mp_encode_array(ptr, 2);
```

– user58626